# PostgreSQL: both roles "root" and "postgres" does not exists

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm using postgres:13.1-alpine image for a docker container. I tried to make a backup of the volume using the following command:

```sh
docker run --rm \ 
  --volume [DOCKER_COMPOSE_PREFIX]_[VOLUME_NAME]:/[TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY_STORING_EXTRACTED_BACKUP] \
  --volume $(pwd):/[TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY_TO_STORE_BACKUP_FILE] \
  ubuntu \
  tar xvf /[TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY_TO_STORE_BACKUP_FILE]/[BACKUP_FILENAME].tar -C /[TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY_STORING_EXTRACTED_BACKUP] --strip 1
```

Something went wrong and now I can't access the database. I used to access it using the user/role `myuser`. But it seems to not exists anymore.

## What I tried

I still can access the container using `docker exec -it postgres sh`. But I can't start `psql` because neither `root`, `postgres` or `myuser` roles exists.

All solutions I have found so far are basically the same: or use postgres user to create another user or use root user to create the role "postgres". This solutions doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your database is toast.  It is hard to see how an innocent backing-up accident could leave you with no predictable users, but an otherwise intact database.  But it is at least plausible that you or docker just blew away your database entirely, then created a new one with a user whose name you wouldn't immediately guess.  So find the size of the data directory, is that most plausible for the database you hope to find, or with one newly created from scratch?

I would run `strings DATADIR/global/1260` and see if it finds anything recognizable as a user name in there, then you could try logging in as that.

Or, you could shutdown the database and restart it in single-user mode, `/path/to/bin/postgres --single -D /path/to/DATADIR` and take a look at pg_authid to see what is in there.